# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I could not  use shared_preferences in flutter when try to import the package.

It always given red underline by prompting 'Target of URI doesn't exist: shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart'

[see the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtKfo.jpg)

I have tried to use the latest version of shared_preferences

```
    name: oirs_flutter
description: A new Flutter project.

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter



cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2 
lottie: ^2.6.0
http: ^1.1.0
fluttertoast: ^8.2.2
shared_preferences: ^2.1.0
path: ^1.8.0
sqflite: ^2.0.0+4


 dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
  sdk: flutter


 flutter_lints: ^2.0.0



 uses-material-design: true


  assets:
   - lib/images/
   - lib/assets/unlock.json
```

Comment: Have you tried to re-run `flutter pub get`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried that, still same thing

Comment: Can you show me all dependencies that you use?

Comment: dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  lottie: ^2.6.0
  http: ^1.1.0
  fluttertoast: ^8.2.2
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.2

Comment: and the environment sdk version?

Comment: environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.1 <4.0.0'

Comment: share your pubspec.yaml file

Comment: Dhafin Rayhan, Please I am expecting your response on the way forward....... thanks for your support so far

Comment: i have update my ubspec.yaml file  above

Comment: I was suspecting package conflicts in your pubspec, but turns out that's not the case. Can you open this folder: `C:\Users\{YOUR NAME}\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev` and see if the `shared_preferences-2.1.0` folder is there?

Comment: How would I locate the directory to  pub.dev on mac? Already searching internet any clew pls

Comment: Maybe try this https://medium.com/mcappmedia/pub-cache-location-in-mac-9557ba391e13